# How do i set the label and display an integer value from a TextBox to the label when the enter key is pressed in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

Here's the code. I have modified it bit?

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int coursenumber;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)

        {
            bool res = int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out coursenumber);
            if (res == true)
            {
                //success
            }


        }
        private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Check if the key that was pressed was the Enter key.
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {

        //logic goes here
            }
        }
```

Comment: What problem do you have? Setting the label, or handling the "enter" key? Try to keep it to just one problem per question

Comment: If you don't use `res` elsewhere in your code, there's no point to create a variable for it. `if (Int16.TryParse(textBox.Text, out coursenumber))`. Additionally, since a bool can *only* be `true` or `false`, you don't need to do an `else if (res == false)` but rather just `else` will suffice. If it's not `true` then it must be `false`, so why bother adding the extra step to evaluate it? That said, the two answers here should work for you. Use the `KeyDown` event instead.

Comment: Why not just bind the TextBox to an Integer?  I

Answer (score 1):

Register to the Key Down event and check

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `KeyDown` event. Subscribe to this event on your `TextBox` like this:

```
<TextBox KeyDown="textBox_KeyDown" ... />
```

And your event handler will look something like this:

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if the key that was pressed was the Enter key.
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        bool res = int.TryParse ...

        //The rest of your logic here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone, i was able to get it working from your responses. here's the modification

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int coursenumber;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        bool res = int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out coursenumber);
        if (res == true)
        {
            //success
        }


    }
    private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if the key that was pressed was the Enter key.
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
           label2.Content = coursenumber;


        }
    }
```